# SAS IML pass reference to variable defined in macro

Tags: macros, reference, module, sas-iml

In SAS/IML I try to pass to a user defined module a reference to a variable that is defined in macro. The module changes the variable value. 
Since call of the function is in the do-loop I cannot use *&-sign*. However use of *symget* does not work. Here is my code.

```
proc iml;
    start funcReference(argOut);

        print "funcReference " argOut;
        argOut = 5;

    finish funcReference;
    store module=funcReference;
quit;

proc IML;
    mydata1 = {1 2 3};
    call symput ('macVar', 'mydata1');

    load module=funcReference;
    run funcReference(symget('macVar'));

    print mydata1;
quit;
```

The output shows that variable *mydata1* have not changed:

```
argOut 
funcReference mydata1 

mydata1 
1 2 3
```

Any ideas?

---

**SOLVED**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending in a temporary scalar matrix (the result of the SYMGET call). That temporary variable is being updated and promptly vanishes, as explained in the article ["Oh, those pesky temporary variables!"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/01/30/temporary-variables/)

Instead of macro variables (which are text strings), you should use the VALUE and VALSET functions, as described in the article ["Indirect assignment: How to create and use matrices named x1, x2,..., xn"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/03/23/indirect-assignment-how-to-create-and-use-matrices-named-x1-x2-xn/)  You need to send in a real matrix in order for the values to be updated correctly, as follows:

```
proc IML;
load module=funcReference;
mydata1 = {1 2 3};
call symput('macVar', 'mydata1');

matrixName = symget('macVar');  /* matrix named &mydata1 */
z = value(matrixName);          /* z contains data */
run funcReference(z);           /* update values in z */
call valset(matrixName, z);     /* update data in &mydata1 */

print mydata1;
```