# SAS IML Use symget on left side

Tags: macros, module, variable-assignment, sas-iml

In SAS/IML is it possible to change a variable if only a macro with its name is available? Using symget on left side produces mistake:

```
proc iml;
    variable = 0;
    call symput ('macVar', 'variable');
/*  &macVar = 1;*/
    symget('macVar') = 1;
    print variable;
quit;

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

The *&-sign* works, but the code is in a do-loop and *symget* must be used.

The problem stems from task to write a function that accepts variable number of arguments and processes them in several do-loops. It is connected with the following questions:

[SAS IML use of Mattrib with Macro (symget) in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837613/sas-iml-use-of-mattrib-with-macro-symget-in-a-loop)

[SAS IML pass reference to variable defined in macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844612/sas-iml-pass-reference-to-variable-defined-in-macro)

[Loop over names in SAS-IML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716726/loop-over-names-in-sas-iml)

In other languages (R, C++, Java, Matlab, etc..) the task is solved with help of abstraction.

Ideas?

---

**SOLVED**

Thanks a lot. 
Useful article.

Answer (score 0):

Use the VALSET subroutine:

```
    call valset(symget('macVar'), 1);
```

You find the article ["Read hundreds of data sets into matrices."](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/31/read-100-data-sets-into-matrices/) helpful, since so many of your questions are about similar.